# CentOS - Apache configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

I have just installed CentOS to use as a server and installed Apache.

I have noticed that the web root is: `/var/www/html`

But I'd like to install an FTP server, which will lock users into their own `/home/username`, which will have a `public_html` folder that will then be that particular users web root, rather than `/var/www/html/username`

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're content to have the user's web site be www.example.com/~username, then you can simply use the apache module [mod_userdir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/public_html.html). If you'd like each user to have their own domain name,  you'd need to utilized [name-based virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html) with each vhost's docroot defined as the user's home directory.

Comment: Well I'd rather have each `/home/username` as a different domain without the `~/username`and they can only access that particular folder. Will I need to use name-based vhosts and an FTP server to achieve this?

Comment: Yes. Take a look at vsftpd's chroot_local_user directive to accomplish the FTP portion of your requirement.